# Symfony 2, how do I handle routing for multiple domains?

Tags: symfony, routes, appdomain, multiple-domains

I have a site that let anyone create there own site with our sub-domain and they can also use there own custom domain.

```
user_site:
    resource: "routing_user_site.yml"
    host:     "{subdomain}.{domain}"
    requirements:
        domain: %domain%
    defaults:
        domain: %domain%

# Our Site
site:
    host: %domain%
    resource: "routing_our_site.yml"
    prefix: /
```

The above route works fine, but I'm not sure how to redirect other domains, which is not our main domain to route routing_user_site.yml file

I have added this, but doesn't work

```
custom_site:
    host: "{domain}"
    resource: "routing_user_site.yml"
    prefix: /
    requirements:
      domain: !(%domain%)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Symfony2, the order of the routes is very important. If one route is not matched, then the framework will test the next.

That means, in your case, that you don't have to do `!(%domain%)`, but just to put a rule without any requirement to catch all other routes.

```
user_site:
    [...]
site:
    [...]
custom_site:
    resource: "routing_user_site.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

If the request is not catched by *user_site* nor *site*, it will be catched by *custom_site* ; and as *user_site* and *site* suggest, *custom_site* will match a user's own domain (or, at least, a domain different from your %domain%).